# adding rnorm to a column in loop

Tags: r, loops

I am doing simulations and am trying to add error to a column repeatedly, specifically to the column titled Ao. In my output, the first 30 rows are correct; we have the initial data, the first year of altered data (error added to Ao), but then afterwards, where I would like to have 30 years of added error, I get repeats of Year 2 for Ao up to year 30. My goal is that I add error after each year of sampling. Ie. Year 2 is Year 1 Ao + error. Year 3 is Year 2 Ao + error, so on and so forth. Any helpers? Cheers.

```
    for(t in 1:30){
      Error<-rnorm(1000,0,1)
      m<-rep(year1data$m,30)
      r<-rep(year1data$r,30)
      a<-rep(year1data$a,30)
      g<-rep(year1data$g,30)
      Year<-rep(2:31, each=TotSpecies)
      Species<-1:TotSpecies
      Ao<-year1data$Ao+sample(Error,TotSpecies,replace=FALSE)
      TotSpeciesdata<-data.frame(Species,Year,Ao,m,r,a,g)
      TotSpeciesdata<-rbind(year1data,TotSpeciesdata)
    }

     > TotSpeciesdata
    Species Year         Ao   m          r         a         g
    1         1    1  25.770783  43 119.110786 3.2305180 2.6526471
    2         2    1  53.908914 138 161.894541 0.7342070 0.1151602
    3         3    1   2.010732 226 193.820489 2.2890904 3.6248105
    4         4    1  23.742254 332  17.315335 1.4009572 2.0037931
    5         5    1   4.291080  63 187.591209 0.2563995 2.1553908
    6         6    1   4.691113 343 116.267867 0.3899113 3.3950085
    7         7    1 604.133044 224 132.240197 3.0410743 0.7985524
    8         8    1  13.332567 166   5.367118 0.7921644 1.7861011
    9         9    1   3.759268 141 212.340970 2.8733737 2.7123141
    10       10    1   3.647390 209 259.400858 0.1249936 0.6594659
    11       11    1  23.731109  10 114.171147 2.2437372 0.9867591
    12       12    1  85.116996  69 167.412993 0.8306823 2.8905148
    13       13    1  31.684280 277 177.025460 2.7618332 2.9245554
    14       14    1  30.657523 205  21.710438 2.7661347 1.5911379
    15       15    1  12.240410  85 210.121109 2.8827455 3.0418454
    16        1    2  27.038097  43 119.110786 3.2305180 2.6526471
    17        2    2  54.251600 138 161.894541 0.7342070 0.1151602
    18        3    2   2.010636 226 193.820489 2.2890904 3.6248105
    19        4    2  22.699369 332  17.315335 1.4009572 2.0037931
    20        5    2   4.542589  63 187.591209 0.2563995 2.1553908
    21        6    2   3.607833 343 116.267867 0.3899113 3.3950085
    22        7    2 604.480756 224 132.240197 3.0410743 0.7985524
    23        8    2  13.663513 166   5.367118 0.7921644 1.7861011
    24        9    2   2.138715 141 212.340970 2.8733737 2.7123141
    25       10    2   3.642769 209 259.400858 0.1249936 0.6594659
    26       11    2  22.897993  10 114.171147 2.2437372 0.9867591
    27       12    2  85.490897  69 167.412993 0.8306823 2.8905148
    28       13    2  31.689202 277 177.025460 2.7618332 2.9245554
    29       14    2  30.644419 205  21.710438 2.7661347 1.5911379
    30       15    2  12.050207  85 210.121109 2.8827455 3.0418454
    31        1    3  27.038097  43 119.110786 3.2305180 2.6526471
    32        2    3  54.251600 138 161.894541 0.7342070 0.1151602
    33        3    3   2.010636 226 193.820489 2.2890904 3.6248105
    34        4    3  22.699369 332  17.315335 1.4009572 2.0037931
    35        5    3   4.542589  63 187.591209 0.2563995 2.1553908
    36        6    3   3.607833 343 116.267867 0.3899113 3.3950085
    37        7    3 604.480756 224 132.240197 3.0410743 0.7985524
    38        8    3  13.663513 166   5.367118 0.7921644 1.7861011
    39        9    3   2.138715 141 212.340970 2.8733737 2.7123141
    40       10    3   3.642769 209 259.400858 0.1249936 0.6594659
    41       11    3  22.897993  10 114.171147 2.2437372 0.9867591
    42       12    3  85.490897  69 167.412993 0.8306823 2.8905148
    43       13    3  31.689202 277 177.025460 2.7618332 2.9245554
    44       14    3  30.644419 205  21.710438 2.7661347 1.5911379
    45       15    3  12.050207  85 210.121109 2.8827455 3.0418454
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please supply your data in [a reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), e.g., using `dput`. It's also unclear what you want. Consider supplying an example of your intended output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem you have with your approach is the line:

```
TotSpeciesdata<-data.frame(Species,Year,Ao,m,r,a,g)
```

Because `Year` is a `30 * TotSpecies` vector, but all the others are just `TotSpecies` long.  So in effect, you are recycling all columns except `Year` 30 times when you create the data frame, which will lead to the year 2 data repeated 30 times, among other things.  If you just have `Year <- rep(i + 1, TotSpecies)` I think your logic will work fine.  That said, here is an alternate approach:

This will, for each species, create an incrementing random walk starting with `Ao` for that species for 5 years (just did that for display purposes):

```
set.seed(1)
year1data <- data.frame(species=1:10, year=1, Ao=runif(10, 1, 700))
TotSpeciesData <- do.call(
  rbind, 
  lapply(
    split(year1data, year1data$species),
    function(data) 
      with(
        data, 
        data.frame(species=species, year=year, Ao=c(Ao, Ao + cumsum(rnorm(5)))
) ) ) )
head(TotSpeciesData, 15)
```

Note I excluded columns m-g since they don't seem directly relevant to your particular question, but you can add them relatively easily.  I also only did 5 years in addition to year 1 so you can see the results here, but that is also easy to change:

```
    species year       Ao
1.1       1    1 186.5906
1.2       1    1 185.7701
1.3       1    1 186.2575
1.4       1    1 186.9958
1.5       1    1 187.5716
1.6       1    1 187.2662
2.1       2    1 261.1146
2.2       2    1 262.6264
2.3       2    1 263.0162
2.4       2    1 262.3950
2.5       2    1 260.1803
2.6       2    1 261.3052
3.1       3    1 401.4245
3.2       3    1 401.3796
3.3       3    1 401.3634
```

Comment: Much appreciated with the help. The first tip: Year<-rep(i + 1, TotSpecies) did not work but I was able to adjust what you gave as an alternative for what I need. Much appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately the code provided didn't seem to work properly. See my comments below.

Answer (score 0):

It has been pointed out that the code that you provided above, or at least that I have edited, repeats itself every 15 years, rather than being unique year year in a step-wise fashion. I edited it as shown below:

```
TotSpeciesData <- do.call(
  rbind, #bind the table by rows
  lapply(    #applying the function in list form
    split(year1data, year1data$Species),   #splits data into groups by species
    function(data) 
      with(
        data, 
        data.frame(Species=Species, Year=1:Community, Ao=c(Ao, Ao + cumsum(rnorm((TotSpecies-1),0,2))),m=m, r=r, a=a, g=g) #data frame is Species, Year, 
        ) ) ) 
  TotSpeciesData$Ao[TotSpeciesData$Ao<0]<-0                 #any values less than 0 go to 0
TotSpeciesData<-TotSpeciesData[order(TotSpeciesData$Year),] #orders the data frame by Year
```

When I do this code:

```
TotSpeciesData[TotSpeciesData$Species==1 & TotSpeciesData$Year %in% c(1,2,16,17),]
```

I end up with an output showing that the data is repeating itself.

```
Species Year       Ao   m        r        a        g   
1.1        1    1 48.49161 239 332.9625 3.791778 2.723104
1.2        1    2 49.62851 239 332.9625 3.791778 2.723104
1.16       1   16 48.49161 239 332.9625 3.791778 2.723104
1.17       1   17 49.62851 239 332.9625 3.791778 2.723104
```

Any comments toward this?

Comment: You need to make sure your `Year` and `Ao` vectors are the same length.  Without the data it's hard to be sure, but I think you need `Ao=c(Ao, Ao + cumsum(rnorm((Community-1),0,2)))` (notice I replaced `TotSpecies` with `Community`) as that way your `Year` and `Ao` vectors end up being the same length.